# Redirection by Pretty Faces

Tags: java, jsf, redirect, prettyfaces

I have come across a problem in which Pretty Faces will result in an infinite loop, ended by my Browser: `Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.`

**The exact cause of the problem**

*File structure*

[image]

*pretty-config.xml fragment*

```
<url-mapping id="login">
    <pattern value="/login" />
    <view-id value="/login/login.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>

<url-mapping id="register">
    <pattern value="/register" />
    <view-id value="/login/register.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

**Description**

Navigation to `localhost:8080/register` will result in my webpage.
Navigation to `localhost:8080/login` will result in the described loop, note that the navigation will result in redirection to `localhost:8080/login/` <-- a trailing slash.

My guess, `localhost:8080/login` is a request for the folder `login`. But I do not know how to fix it, so my request for `localhost:8080/login` will result in the webpage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your deployment descriptor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My only guess is that your `FacesServlet` is mapped to `*.xhtml` so when a request is processed, first your pretty filter forwards it to your FacesServlet, but, because your xhtml files are in the path, the forward is then again processed by your pretty filter ad infinitum.

To solve it, put your views inside the WEB-INF folder and in your `pretty.config.xml` put something like this:

```
 <url-mapping id="login">
    <pattern value="/login/" />
    <view-id value="/WEB-INF/views/login.xhtml" />
 </url-mapping>
```

This way the path intercepted by the filter is not the same of your servlet because clients can request resources in the `WEB-INF` folder

Comment: Your right, this will be processed by FacesServlet again. But wouldn't this be the same for `register`?

Comment: No because the file is in `/login/register.xhtml` so it does not match `<pattern value="/register" />` because the trailing `/login/` in your file path.

Comment: Oh ok, like that, I thought I wildcard at the end would be required for that one. I understand it fully now, thank you Mael!

Comment: No, a pattern like "/login" definitively doesn't match the forwarded request to "/login/login.xhtml". Forwarded request are not matched against mapping patterns. I think it is more likely the issue I described in my response below.

Comment: That is actually a true answer

Answer (score 5):

I also had this problem in the past. The problem is your Servlet container. If you are requesting an URL like `/login`, you container checks, if there is a directory in you web app that is named `login`. If so, it redirects you to `/login/`, because the container thinks that you want to reach this directory. If there are also rewrite rules that remove trailing slashes, you will see a behavior like this.

I know that this is strange, but some guy on the tomcat user list wrote, that this behavior is according to the spec.

So the only solution would be to either change `/login` to `/login/` in your mapping or to rename the login folder in your webapp.

Comment: You seem to be correct, I was somehow a bit confused as I have been experimenting with some filters. This turned out that indeed a (by Pretty Faces) redirected request would not pass Pretty Faces again and therefor cannot lead to the situation as Mael described.